# How to read user input into a string ignoring certain characters

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, input

I am trying to get a string of just upercase A - G chars ignoring any other characters in the alphabet. I tried a long if statement such as:

```
    String initString;

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        if (input.equals("A") || input.equals("B") || input.equals("C") || input.equals("D") || input.equals("E") || input.equals("F") || input.equals("G")){
            initString = intiString + input.next();
        }

    }
```

but had problems, an example would be an input string of  AAAADDDGGIJUBBBB
but the string saved to intiString would be AAAADDDGGBBBB. How would I add to the string after every iteration because simply trying to add input.next and intiString isnt working.

Comment: Please could let us know what problem are you facing? And do you want user to enter input character by character and make a string from it ? or the user will enter the whole string and then you want to process it?

Comment: What is `intiString` in `initString = intiString + input.next();` I suspect typo

Comment: @BalwinderSingh It is just what I named the string that my input is going to.

Comment: Like I said it is a typo. Plus you should use regex for character comparison to avoid long if condition. Also, where is the logic for user to stop giving more input (I assume user is entering one character at a time - which is being processed)

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I wanted the user to type in the entire String in one go

Comment: It will be better if you could share more code than this as currently not each field is clear to SO users

Comment: Well, try with my code, separates the characters of uppercase letters from A to G and converts it into a string, I hope it serves you

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
char cont;
String initString = "";
do{
   Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in); 
   String input = sc.next();

   for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){ 
      char ch =  input.charAt(i);
      if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'G'){
         initString = initString + ch;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to enter more words(Y/N)");
    cont = sc.next().charAt(0); 
}while(cont != 'N');
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is pretty wrong.  `next()` is normally an Iterator method, and Iterator is not a String.  Since you check `equal()` before `next()` you're not even checking the character you actually get.

Anyway. Instead of loop, it may be easier to just take the input string and drop unwanted characters:

```
String input = "AAAADDDGGIJUBBBB";
String initString = Pattern.compile( "[^A-G]++" ).matcher( input ).replaceAll( "" );
// initString = "AAAADDDGGBBBB"
```

Or if you really, really want to use a looped if instead of regular expression:

```
String input = "AAAADDDGGIJUBBBB";
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( input.length() );
for ( int codepoint : input.chars().toArray() ) // You can also use char, slightly simpler
   if ( codepoint >= 'A' && codepoint <= 'G' )
      buf.append( Character.toChars( codepoint ) ); // Simply append the char here
String initString = buf.toString();
// initString = "AAAADDDGGBBBB"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try with this

```
public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println(getAG("JUUYYTTYYGAAAFIUFF")); //This returns GAAAFFF
        }

        public static String getAG(String input)
        {
            String outValue = "";
            for(char c:input.toCharArray())
            {
                if(c >= 'A' && c<= 'G')
                {
                    outValue += "" + c;
                }
            }
            return outValue;
        }
    }
```